# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar "try" o "if" en cualquier lenguaje de programación como Python, C o Java?

Tags: java, python, c, condiciones, try-catch

> **Usaré un ejemplo con la sintaxis de Python, si bien la sintaxis de estas estructuras son diferentes en cada lenguajes, esta pregunta es valida para otros lenguajes con los que tengo la misma duda, como en C y Java**.

Supongamos un programa que realice una división, si el denominador es 0, da el caso de usar o bien un **"try"** o un **"if"** para indicar que no es posible realizar la división entre 0 sin que se produzca un error pragmático, el programa empleando **"try"** es el siguiente:

```
import os

numerador = 4
denominador = 0

try:
    division = numerador / denominador
    print("El resultado de la division es " + division)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("No se puede realizar la division")

os.system("pause")
```

El mismo programa solo que en vez de usar **"try"** uso **"if"** :

```
import os

numerador = 4
denominador = 0

if denominador != 0:
    division = numerador / denominador
    print("El resultado de la division es " + division)
else:
    print("No se puede realizar la division")

os.system("pause")
```

Si bien el resultado del programa es el mismo en ambos casos (imprime que no es posible realizar la división), entonces, ¿Cuál es más adecuado usar y porque?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En el caso que pones de ejemplo, diría que no hay mayor diferencia. Es decir, ninguno es más adecuado que el otro, sin embargo, el caso que pones es uno que es muy simple y no todos los casos en donde ocurriría una excepción se pueden reducir a un `if` que compruebe o evite que ocurra.

### Excepciones

Hablemos primero un poco de excepciones, y quisiera comenzar diciendo que el invento de las excepciones y su manejo es, en mi opinión, uno de los grandes logros y de los diferenciadores entre un lenguaje *moderno* y uno que no lo es.

Imaginemos un caso un poco más general, para ver **que es una excepción**.

Tenemos una función que realiza la división como tal, no imprime nada y no debe hacerlo, simplemente realiza el cálculo y va a ser utilizada a lo largo y ancho del sistema siempre que haya que hacer una división.

Utilizaré sintaxis de pascal para ejemplificar, pero vale cualquier lenguaje moderno. La firma de la división es:

```delphi
function Dividir(Dividendo, Divisor: Double): Double;
```

Y el contrato es: Si la división puede hacerse, se hace, y si no, **se eleva una excepción**, lo cual pone a todo el programa en un estado especial, que interrumpe el flujo normal de la ejecución, hasta que se encuentre al código capaz de gestionar dicho estado de excepción y devolver el programa a su estado normal.

Además de este cambio en el flujo de ejecución del programa, la excepción va acompañada de un *objeto* que acarrea información sobre lo que ocurrió. Esta información generalmente contiene un mensaje de error y una copia de la pila de llamadas al momento en que ocurrió el error. No tiene que limitarse a eso, puede contener cualquier otra información que sea de utilidad para informar y diagnosticar la situación que ha provocado el error.

Quizás no sea fácil apreciar el valor de esto, así que revisemos un poco la historia:

### Qué existía antes de las excepciones

Antes de la existencia de las excepciones, cuando ocurría un error, generalmente se utilizaban *valores bandera* para indicar esta situación, o se activaban *flags* que indicaban que había ocurrido un error.

Esto provocaba que todo el código estuviera plagado de validaciones para determinar si el estado del programa era normal y continuar con el flujo principal de operaciones, o si se había un estado de error que requería un tratamiento especial.

Esto era particularmente difícil de manejar en las *fronteras* entre bibliotecas, que podían tener mecanismos diferentes para señalar y manejar estados de error y hacía que fuese complicado, si no imposible, propagar la información de error más allá del código que uno mismo escribía.

No voy a profundizar más en el tema, porque esta ya es una respuesta bastante larga, pero ya que hoy en día se siguen utilizando muchos lenguajes que no soportan excepciones, te invito a investigar y explorar cómo se maneja una situación de error, de preferencia en un sistema grande, en ensamblador, o en c.

Afortunadamente para nosotros, tenemos ahora el

### Manejo de excepciones

Hay básicamente tres características que hacen que los programas hechos con lenguajes que soportan excepciones sean más fáciles de mantener, sin sacrificar robustez.

- Podemos escribir código que se ejecute independientemente de que el programa esté en estado de excepción. Esto nos permite lograr de manera muy fácil

  - Garantizar la *limpieza* necesaria, por ejemplo, en conexiones a bases de datos u otros sistemas similares.
  - Llevar registros
  - Hacer un uso eficiente de recursos que de otra forma sería difícil controlar
- Podemos escribir (o no) código para manejar un estado de excepción en el nivel adecuado
- La información de una excepción puede atravesar fácilmente las fronteras entre bibliotecas de distintos fabricantes y nuestro propio código, sin perder información, lo cual hace muy sencillo propagar su información hasta donde sea necesario.

No quiero extenderme más, te dejo algunos recursos para que leas:

- [Manejo de excepciones (Wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manejo_de_excepciones)
- Buenas prácticas:

  - [Cumple el contrato o muere intentándolo](https://coderr.io/exception-handling/Fulfil-the-contract-or-die-trying) (en inglés)
  - [No caches las excepciones](https://coderr.io/exception-handling/Do-not-catch-that-exception!) (en inglés)

Answer (score 5):

Python no es el mejor ejemplo, dado que su sintaxis invita mucho a usar bloques `try-catch`  para controlar el flujo del código (y debido al [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing))

De todas maneras, de forma general la respuesta a **¿Cuál es más adecuado usar y porque?** es:

- Si puedes gestionar localmente (en esa función o método) el error, usa un if.
- Si no puedes gestionar localmente el error, tira una excepción y escalas el problema al nivel superior.

En tu ejemplo lo lógico sería usar un `if`, ya que ahí mismo puedes enviarle un mensaje al usuario diciendo que no puede dividir entre 0. Si estás en un método dentro de un objeto que no tiene acceso a la manera de solucionar el problema, por ejemplo, un método que parsea algo recibido por socket, lo suyo es tirar una excepción y que la clase que se encarga de la lógica del socket gestione ese problema, ya que dentro del método que parsea no deberías estar haciendo nada más que eso, parsear el texto recibido.

Espero haberme explicado.

Answer (score 3):

En realidad aquí estas realizando mediante el [manejo de excepciones](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/#:%7E:text=Remove%20ads-,The%20try%20and%20except%20Block%3A%20Handling%20Exceptions,in%20the%20preceding%20try%20clause) una captura de error, en caso de el error `ZeroDivisionError` imprimes un mensaje:

```
try:
    division = numerador / denominador
    print("El resultado de la division es " + division)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("No se puede realizar la division")

os.system("pause")
```

En el segundo caso estas realizando una validación para evitar la división entre cero.

```
import os

numerador = 4
denominador = 0

if denominador != 0:
    division = numerador / denominador
    print("El resultado de la division es " + division)
else:
    print("No se puede realizar la division")

os.system("pause")
```

En programación realizamos un manejo de excepciones para manejar algún posible error, pero debemos evitar obtener errores, por esta razón los mejor es principalmente validar para evitar errores en lugar de esperar una respuesta al provocarse un error.

Answer (score 2):

Una pregunta en principio inocente, si la miras de lejos, pero que tiene más chicha de la que parece.

Para responder a tu pregunta, se puede usar básicamente dos enfoques: a nivel de lenguaje, o a nivel de hardware. Sea como fuere, hay que hablar de ensamblador, traducción, excepciones e interrupciones.

A nivel de la máquina, ten en cuenta que tu ordenador tiene un procesador, con un conjunto de instrucciones que puede ejecutar. Entre ellas, tenemos los saltos condicionales e incondicionales, que se utilizan para conseguir el comportamiento habitual de los `if`.

Una sentencia de control de flujo como la siguiente:

```
int i = 0;
if (i == 0) i++;
else i--;
```

Se podría traducir a algo como lo siguiente (pseudo MIPS, que es fácil de entender):

```
    addi $1, $zero, $zero    # Cargamos el valor 0 en i ($1)
    lw   $sp, $1             # Guardamos el contenido de i ($1 = 0) en la pila ($sp)
_if:
    jnez $1, _else    # Salta a la instrucción tras la etiqueta _else si i != 0
_then:
    addi $1, $1, 1    # i++ -> Guarda en i ($1) el resultado de sumar 1 a i
    j    _endif       # Salta hasta después del _else, aka _endif, para no ejecutar el _else
_else:
    subi $1, $1, 1    # i-- -> Guarda en i ($1) el resultado de restar 1 a i
_endif:
    mv   $v0, 0    # Carga 0 en un registro resultado
    j    $ra       # Vuelve al invocador (return 0)
```

Aunque parece mucho, un `if` implica pocas instrucciones al traducirse a código máquina en lenguajes compilados (como C), y de igual forma, pocas traducciones en lenguajes interpretados.

Ahora bien, cuando se lanza una excepción, y se captura en un bloque `try-catch`, ocurren muchas cosas más:

- Se detiene la ejecución del hilo, guardando el estado del mismo (muchas instrucciones de escritura en memoria).
- Se reserva memoria para almacenar la información de la excepción, que generalmente va a estar almacenada en un objeto, cuya construcción conlleva más instrucciones.
- Se busca un manejador de excepción en el código que invocó la llamada.
- Si no se encuentra manejador, la excepción se propaga de manera recursiva, hasta alcanzar el `main`.
- En caso de encontrar código para manejar la excepción, recuperar el estado del hilo.

En definitiva, en términos de tiempo de procesador, un `if` implica pocas instrucciones, y por tanto pocos ciclos de procesador y poco tiempo de ejecución (un ciclo de procesador habitualmente es de menos de 1 nano segundo); mientras que una excepción es muy costosa en tiempo (en comparación con un `if`), requiriendo hasta varios cientos de ciclos (o más).

Por tanto, desde el punto de vista de la eficiencia, lo mejor es utilizar un `if` para evitar que se lance una excepción.

Especial es el caso de la división entre 0. Dependiendo del procesador, el resultado puede ser un valor `NaN` que representa que el resultado no es un número; o bien, algo muy común es que se produzca una interrupción.

Mientras que una excepción es una entidad *software*, ya que "alguien" (alguna sección de código) la tiene que construir y lanzar (y el usuario la tiene que atrapar)...

```
int miDivision(int dividendo, int divisor)
{
    if (divisor == 0) throw new ExcepcionDivisionEntreCero();
    return dividendo / divisor;
}

// ...

main(...)    // No lo defino porque es válido para varios lenguajes distintos
{
    try
    {
        int resultado = miDivision(1, 0);
        // Hacer algo con el resultado
    }
    catch (ExcepcionDivisionEntreCero)
    {
        // Manejar la excepción
    }
}
```

Una interrupción es una señal que se produce en el *hardware* de tu ordenador, y concretamente, en el procesador.

Una interrupción es una señal que se produce cuando no se puede ejecutar alguna instrucción en el procesador (como acceder a zonas que la memoria que no te pertenecen, o que todavía no han sido reservadas, o dividir entre cero).

En estos casos, la interrupción detiene tu programa y le pasa el control al sistema operativo, cuyo núcleo tiene que decidir qué hacer con dicha interrupción (cargar una página todavía no presente en memoria, abortar la ejecución de tu programa, etc.).

Este cambio entre tu proceso y el núcleo tiene un coste todavía mayor que el de una excepción, por lo que en algunos casos también conviene evitar situaciones que provoquen una interrupción (hay casos en los que no se puede, como los fallos de página).

Ahora bien, desde el punto de vista del *software*, un buen diseño generalmente hace uso de excepciones, ya que el manejo de errores se simplifica una barbaridad, y se hace de manera más correcta, como se ha explicado en otras respuestas, por lo que no volveré a entrar en ese enfoque.

Solo ten en mente que, generalmente, hay que encontrar un punto intermedio entre eficiencia y buen diseño (generalmente los malos diseños tienden a ser más eficientes, pero más difíciles de mantener, y propensos a que cometas errores de programación).

Como regla general, no debes esconder errores de programación con excepciones, como cuando ejecutas un método sobre un objeto nulo. Pero sí que puedes prevenir algunas situaciones con `if`, sobre todo cuando son validaciones de datos introducidos por usuarios.